# how remove children form dynamicly added sections

Tags: vue.js

Hello I took over the vue project and right now i'm working on module that dynamicly adds and delate sections. Each section has opton to ceate elements also by v-for. My problem is that buttons for delateing elemnts don't konw in which section exists.

symptoms:
In first section i'm adding 3 elements and console returns
this.$ref.index > (3) [tr, tr, tr]
nex i'm creating another section and adding one elemnt then clg shows
this.$ref.index > (4) [tr, tr, tr, tr,]

i't should't be like that righ?
do you have any ide how to compare elemnts with right sections

[Visualisation of components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogCae.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your given visualization of layout, I believe the structure of your element should be:

```
Main (adds Sestions and listens for Sestion removal)
  Sestion (adds Elements, listens for Element removal, emit remove event)
    Element (emit remove event)
    Element
  Sestion
    Element
    Element
```

the code would look something like this:

```html
/** Sestion.vue **/
<template>
  <div>
    <ElementCard
      v-for="(element, index) in elements"
      :key="index"
      @remove="onRemoveElement(index)"
    />

    <button @click="onAddElement">
      Add
    </button>

    <button @click="$emit('remove')">
      Remove
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      elements: []
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onAddElement() {
      this.elements.push();
    },

    onRemoveElement(index) {
      this.elements.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```